# CSS in ajax loaded content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I am developing a site which has content dynamically produces by php loaded via jquery load. Different content requires different styling which at the moment I am getting via a getjson call in the load callback function. I am using bbq to load the content to enable correct back button functionality. All this mostly works except that when using the back button css from the previous call is applied. the getjson call is to a time stamped page so the correct css data is loaded but the browser uses the cached css. I'd like to avoid firing a new load to refresh the loaded content and apply fresh css, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried loading the CSS file with a timestamped query string?

```
'http://path.to/your.css?v=' + new Date().toString();
```

Comment: The css is dynamically generated depending on the conetnt so there is no css file (other tha base default css), the data for the css in json encoded then jquery getjson loads the data and getjson callback function uses data to amend css